# Welches Wort kann »Bild(zeitungs)niveau« in Österreich ersetzen?

Tags: austrian

Welches in Österreich verständliche Wort kann *Bildzeitungsniveau* bzw. *Bild-niveau* ersetzen?

Am besten nach dem Motto:

> `<Name einer nicht-so-besonders-guten Zeitung>`zeitungsniveau

oder

> `<Name einer nicht-so-besonders-guten Zeitung>`niveau

Comment: Eindeutig die Krone-Zeitung. Es gibt aber auch eine gratis Tageszeitung mit sehr fragwürdigem Niveau, mit Namen [Österreich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreich_%28Tageszeitung%29)

Comment: Ja, am ehesten die Krone, auch wenn sie zwar Boulevard, inhaltlich aber nur bedingt mit der Bild zu vergleichen ist. Wenn's noch eine Spur tiefer sein soll böte sich in der Tat "Österreich" an.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass die *Österreich* noch recht jung ist, erkennt man bei *Österreich-Niveau* leider nicht eindeutig, dass die Zeitung gemeint ist. Es fehlt also die klare Unterscheidung vom allgemeinen Sudern gegen das Land.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ganz klar:

> Kronenzeitungsniveau

Die Krone war von 1892 bis 1924 die amtliche Währung in Österreich. In dieser Zeit erschien zum ersten Mal eine Boulevardzeitung, die genau eine Krone kostete: Die **Kronenzeitung**.

Sie erscheint im ganzen Bundesgebiet und ist derzeit die auflagenstärkste Tageszeitung Österreichs. Da es in Österreich aber eine Reihe sehr guter Lokalzeitungen gibt (Salzburger Nachrichten, OÖ Nachrichten, Kleine Zeitung), gibt es aber Regionen in Österreich, in denen die »*Krone*« dennoch nicht die Nummer 1 ist.

Da ich die deutsche Bild-Zeitung nicht kenne (ich kenne nur den Namen, habe aber noch nie ein Exemplar in der Hand gehabt), kann ich sie nicht mit österreichischen Zeitungen vergleichen.

Die Kronenzeitung hat schon sehr lange den Ruf ein Blatt mit niedrigem Niveau zu sein. In jüngerer Zeit sind aber neue Zeitungen auf den Markt gekommen, deren Niveau nicht nur ich als noch schlechter einschätze. Das sind:

- **Heute**
  eine Gratis-Zeitung, die nur durch Werbung finanziert wird. Anfangs wurde *Heute* in den Wiener U-Bahnen aufgelegt, heute gibt es *Heute* in allen größeren Städten Österreichs. Sie hat selten mehr als 20 Seiten, und berichtet mit Vorliebe, und gerne einseitig von Verbrechen, die im Verbreitungsgebiet der Zeitung geschehen sind. Auch beliebt: Berichte, in denen Prominente (sehr oft Politiker) an den Pranger gestellt werden. Bei positiven Berichten kann man sich sicher sein, im selben Heft „*zufällig*“ auch eine dazu passende große (und teuer bezahlte) Werbeeinschaltung zu finden.
- **Österreich**
  Diese Zeitung kann man kaufen, häufig gibt es sie aber auch gratis. In einem Witz, der vor allem zur Anfangszeit von *Österreich* häufig zu hören war, wurde behauptet, dass sich die Rechtschreibfehler, die man aus anderen Zeitungen herausgestrichen hat, irgendwo angehäuft hätten, wo dann jemand die Idee hatte, aus diesen gesammelten Fehlern eine Zeitung zu machen, die man dann *Österreich* nannte. Inhaltlich macht *Österreich* *Heute* Konkurenz.

Diese neuen schlechten Zeitungen sind aber erst entstanden, nachdem sich *Kronenzeitungsniveau* bereits als Begriff für schlechten Journalismus längst etabliert hatte. Zudem wären die Begriffe »*Heuteniveau*« und noch mehr »*Österreichniveau*« verwirrend für jemanden, der diese Zeitungen nicht kennt.

Answer (score 4):

*Krone-Niveau* dürfte soweit ich weiß recht nah an Bild-Niveau herankommen (Kronen Zeitung). Aber ob das *so* von den netten Nachbarn verwendet wird? :)

Comment: Nach ein paar Jahren in Wien kann ich sagen: Absolut! Auf derstandard.at gibt es 347 Google-Treffer für "Krone-Niveau". Viele davon sind im Diskussionsforum, einige auch im redaktionellen Teil. Bei Deutschlandbezug einer Nachricht wird gelegentlich im selben Atemzug auch noch "Bild-Niveau" als die deutsche Variante genannt.

Comment: Danke für die Auswertung!